# Retrieve data from sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I try to retrieve data from sqlite. Unfortunately the table is filled with null values.
The console shows `FIRST ID RECUPERÉ : (null)`. Can you give me your opinions please?

This is the code:

```
NSString * statementID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id_message FROM messages;"];
const char * sql_stmt_id  = [statementID UTF8String];


sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, sql_stmt_id, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        [tableauMsgReceived removeAllObjects];

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            [tableauMsgReceived addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)]];
            NSLog(@"First ID : %@", [tableauMsgReceived objectAtIndex:0]);
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(contactDB);
```

Comment: What's the SQL statement being run? You're saying the NSLog of First ID prints a null?

Comment: You need to provide more details. What actually happens when you run this code?

Comment: You should extract the row data into a `char*` pointer first, then convert to NSString as a separate step.  That allows you to examine the "raw" data.

Comment: So what value is sqlite3_column_text returning??

Comment: Are you sure that `tableauMsgReceived` isn't `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that the `NSLog` statement will give that result given your code is if `tableauMsgReceived` is `nil`.

Somewhere you need to do:

```
tableauMsgReceived = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have done something like

```
tableauMsgReceived = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Then, check whether database opened successfully

```
if (sqlite3_open([YourDBPath UTF8String], &yourDatabase) == SQLITE_OK){}
```

Last thing, maybe you can try

```
[tableauMsgReceived addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
```